# tkinter listbox mixer plays one song at a time

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I can't figure out how to get a tkinter list box to play continuous audio files in my Music Player without using classes, which I don't fully understand yet since I am new to python.
I already created an event by following examples ,that prints the song that played and the next song in the list box but I don't know how to move from there.

```
SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)

def check_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == SONG_END:
            print('music end event')
            for i in listbox.curselection():
                nxt_song = listbox.get(i + 1)
                print(nxt_song)

    root.after(100, check_event)

def next_s ():
# i cant figure out how to proceed from here to
# get the nxt song and play it
    pass

def play():
# activates the play button
    current = listbox.get(ACTIVE)
    playing_song['text'] = current # goes to a label displaying the current track name
    mixer.music.load(current)
    mixer.music.play()

# everything works as i want exept continuous play
# note that i dont want the player to have previous and next buttons
```

Comment: Your `check_event` function is happening every .1 seconds is that what you really want?  If you have been able to `print` the next song via the binding  to `nxt_song` then what is stopping you from using that?  It's easier to make suggestions when you add your attempt.  What did you try inside of `next_s` that didn't work?

Comment: I dont know how to use it..I cant get the variable nxt_song out of the check_event function..i try to copy the function in new function next_s but i get listbox or nxt_song errors..then i tried to load and play in the next_s function but igot the same errors..after searching for examples i found that such functions were part of a huge class or they were getting the sting values of the playlist form open file directory but that is not what i need,,i need to get nxt_song as a variable to load and play when the check_event happens.

Comment: Hi Rory..do yo have any idea how to activate the check_event function at the last n seconds of the song instead of have it running every .1 sec?

Answer (score 0):

It would be the same thing as playing the song. You would have to do

`pygame.mixer.load(next_song)` `pygame.mixer.play()`

Also you would have to adjust the value of the current song so that it will it moving in the list.

`current = next_song`

```
SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)

current = None

def check_event():
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == SONG_END:
         pygame.mixer.music.stop()
         next_s()

def next_s():
  next_song = listbox.curselection()
  next_song = next_song[0] + 1
  current = listbox.get(next_song)
  pygame.mixer.music.load(current)
  pygame.mixer.music.play()
  listbox.selection_clear(0, END)
  listbox.activate(next_song)
  listbox.selection_set(next_song, last = None)

def play():
  # activates the play button
  current = listbox.get(ACTIVE)
  playing_song['text'] = current # goes to a label displaying the 
  current track name
  pygame.mixer.music.load(current)
  pygame.mixer.music.play()

# everything works as i want exept continuous play
# note that i dont want the player to have previous and next button
```

Comment: Can you please be a little more specifiq..nxt_song is not defined outside the check_event function..i tried global but didnt work either..my question is how do i insert this variable in the play function?

Comment: You would have to set the current song variable outside of the functions so it can be accessed. Remove everything below print(“music end event”) and just call the next_s function. Then find the next song in list of the current song and set that to the current song. Then load the new current song and play it.

Comment: next_song = next_song[0] + 1 creates error tuple index out of range

Comment: You would have to add a if statement checking if there are any more songs, if there is that will run, if not it should play the first song.

Comment: I also made a music player. This might help you: https://github.com/Darkshadogt/Dark-Music-Player

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to put the logic of finding next song into `next_s()` instead:

```py
def check_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == SONG_END:
            print('music end event')
            next_s() # play next song
    root.after(100, check_event)

def next_s():
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        i = listbox.curselection()[-1] + 1
        if i < listbox.size():
            next_song = listbox.get(i)
            print(f"{next_song=}")
            # update selection
            listbox.selection_clear(0, "end")
            listbox.selection_set(i)
            # play next song
            play()
        else:
            print("no more song")

def play():
    selection = listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        current = listbox.get(selection[-1])
        playing_song['text'] = current
        pygame.mixer.music.load(current)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

Comment: i = listbox.curseselection()[-1] + 1 creates error tupple index out of range,,if i replace with for loop goes immediately to print " no more song"

Answer (score 0):

So here is the code that works and allows the Music Player for continuous play..thanks for the inputs that helped a lot.
There is a new problem now

If i press the stop Button the music_stop fnction is a check_event and auto starts playback of the next song.I can always press mute and resume and deactivate the music_stop function or remove the music_stop function and button but i would appreciate any ideas that will separate the music_stop function from check_event.
I already tried :
if event.type == SONG_END and not music_stop
in the check_music function but it prevents the next song to load and i am back
where i started!

```
pygame.init()
SONG_END = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.mixer.music.set_endevent(SONG_END)

def check_event():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == SONG_END:
            print('music end event')
            for i in listbox.curselection():
                next_s()

    root.after(100, check_event)

def next_s():
    # assume there is at least one item selected
    for i in listbox.curselection():
        if i < listbox.size():
            next_song = listbox.get(i + 1)
            print(f"{next_song=}")
            # update selection
            listbox.selection_clear(0, "end")
            listbox.selection_set(i + 1)
            # play next song
            mixer.music.load(next_song)
            mixer.music.play()
        else:
            print("no more song")

def pause_song():
    mixer.music.pause()

def play():
    current_song = listbox.get(ACTIVE)
    playing_song['text'] = current_song
    mixer.music.load(current_song)
    mixer.music.play()


def resume_song():
    mixer.music.unpause()

def music_stop():
    #mixer.music.stop()
    pass
```

Comment: Note that `next_s()` will raise exception when it is executed after playing the last song in the listbox because `next_song` is an empty string.

Comment: Well you ae right..i havnt dealt with such an instance yet because the list is long and i always close the programme before the end of the list..so how to catch this exception?  if i reloop to first tract when last track is been played by using the listbox index..any suggestions on that?